# PathNotFoundException {} while accessing a node in cq5

Tags: nodes, aem

I'm getting a PathNotFoundException in cq5 while accessing a node. I'm trying to extract the data of a pdf file from its jcr:content node. but i'm getting path not found exception because name of my file contains spaces because it sling not able to map the request to corresponding file. My file name is "Sbi FB Deals Done.pdf" which is getting converted by my code into /content/dam/sbi/personal/docs/Sbi%20FB%20Deals%20Done.pdf

due to %20its not getting map with file.
here is my code where i'm getting this exception

```
Node fileNode = session.getNode(filePath+"/jcr:content/renditions/original/jcr:content");           
            inputStream = fileNode.getProperty("jcr:data").getBinary().getStream();
```

where file path is /content/dam/sbi/personal/docs/Sbi FB Deals Done.pdf

any idea for this ? any way to access a file who contains spaces in cq5

Comment: Did you try to keep the spaces when you load the node? And I would start just with the filePath and use the API to get to the renditions, there are already methods on the Asset class to get the stream.

Comment: can you please explain that method i just want the stream of that file by giving my path

Answer (score 0):

To be able to format code propery I post this as an answer.
This is how I did it in a similar case, though I get the node from a search and I am using the `ResourceResolver` and `Adaptable` Interface from the `Resource`:

```
String filePath = "/content/dam/sbi/personal/docs/Sbi FB Deals Done.pdf";
InputStream fileStream = null;
try {
    Asset asset = resolver.resolve(filePath).adaptTo(Asset.class);
    fileStream = asset.getOriginal().getStream();
    //do whatever you need to do with the stream
} catch (IOException e) {
} finally {
    IOUtils.closeQuietly(fileStream);
}
```

Comment: its still throwing same exception at Node fileNode = session.getNode(filePath); . because there is space in my file name and whenever session trying to get ot he's not getting that path

Comment: error occurred while sending mail in sbiMailWithAttachment PathNotFoundException {} /content/dam/sbi/personal/docs/sbi%20CB%20Deals%20Done.pdf

Comment: I removed the JCR part in the code example, maybe the ResourceResolver is more tolerant regarding spaces in the path.